# count number of files with a given extension in a directory - C++?

Tags: c++, file-io, directory, file-extension

Is it possible in c++ to count the number of files with a given extension in a directory?

I'm writing a program where it would be nice to do something like this (pseudo-code):

```
if (file_extension == ".foo")
    num_files++;
for (int i = 0; i < num_files; i++)
    // do something
```

Obviously, this program is much more complex, but this should give you the general idea of what I'm trying to do.

If this is not possible, just tell me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing in the C or C++ *standards* themselves about directory handling but just about any OS worth its salt will have such a beast, one example being the `findfirst/findnext` functions or `readdir`.

The way you would do it is a simple loop over those functions, checking the end of the strings returned for the extension you want.

Something like:

```
char *fspec = findfirst("/tmp");
while (fspec != NULL) {
    int len = strlen (fspec);
    if (len >= 4) {
        if (strcmp (".foo", fspec + len - 4) == 0) {
            printf ("%s\n", fspec);
        }
    }
    fspec = findnext();
}
```

As stated, the actual functions you will use for traversing the directory are OS-specific.

For UNIX, it would almost certainly be the use of [opendir](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/opendir.html), [readdir](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/readdir.html) and [closedir](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/closedir.html). This code is a good starting point for that:

```
#include <dirent.h>

int len;
struct dirent *pDirent;
DIR *pDir;

pDir = opendir("/tmp");
if (pDir != NULL) {
    while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir)) != NULL) {
        len = strlen (pDirent->d_name);
        if (len >= 4) {
            if (strcmp (".foo", &(pDirent->d_name[len - 4])) == 0) {
                printf ("%s\n", pDirent->d_name);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir (pDir);
}
```

Comment: In both cases above. Would a for(;;) loop not be neater?

Comment: Matter of taste or style, I think, @Martin. I tend to use for loops for simple things (mostly the "for i = 1 to 10" sort) and use while for more complicated loops. But in either case, not really relevant to the question at hand.

Answer (score 6):

This kind of functionality is OS-specific, therefore there is no standard, portable method of doing this.

However, using [Boost's Filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) you can do this, and much more file system related operations in a portable manner.

Answer (score 1):

First of all what OS are you writing for?

- If it is Windows then look for `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` in MSDN.
- If you are looking the code for POSIX systems, read `man` for `opendir` and `readdir` or `readdir_r`.
- For cross platform I'd suggest using Boost.Filesystem library.